# Saving Documents to iCloud when there is no Network / Internet

Tags: objective-c, ios, file-upload, icloud

I am new to iCloud, and I am saving my document to iCloud via

```
NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
```

With this method

```
– setUbiquitous:itemAtURL:destinationURL:error:
```

I move the saved document from the NSDocument folder to the ubiquitous folder by the above method if `ubiq` returns true. It works fine when there is network. What should I do when there is no network and if I need to save the document to iCloud? I surfed for this and couldn't find any related to this. Can someone suggest me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If iCloud can't be reached, you obviously can't save anything there.
Display an appropriate error message via an alert and tell the user what is wrong and what to do to fix it.